# UEFI C program runs fine compiled with VS2010 but not VS2012

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, uefi

This is kinda odd question but i am out of ideas and are hoping for help.

I am writing programs for UEFI in C and compile them with the UDK build script which is utilizing Visual Studio compilers. I wrote a simple Hello World program to rule out other factors.

Here is the thing: If i compile the program with VS2012x86 and 64 bit as target and architecture, the program will start but shows nothing than an invinite long blinking cursor. If i choose VS2010x86 as target, it works fine.

What on earth is my problem or how can i find it out (without debugging it on hardware)?

***EDIT***:

```
#include <Uefi.h>
#include <Library/UefiApplicationEntryPoint.h>
#include <Library/UefiLib.h>

EFI_STATUS
EFIAPI
UefiMain (
    EFI_HANDLE        ImageHandle,
    EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE  *SystemTable
  )
{
    Print(L"\nHello World - i gonna test u!\n");

    return EFI_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You can find differences between VS2010 and VS2012 runtime libraries online.  Without  any code, it is difficult to say what problem you face.  Do you run the code as part of the boot process?

Comment: No, i run it in the EFI shell. I added my code in the main post :)

Comment: Are you sure a 64 bit target is expected?

Comment: Yes, because i use a 64 bit EFI shell.

Comment: Yet the 32 bit VS2010 code runs and not the VS2012 64 bit code...  Try setting the VS2012 target to 32  bits.

Comment: Not working. Let me try to clear it up:
The program has to be compiled for 64 bit OS.
If i use VS2012 with the 64 bit target, the program just blinks with the cursor.
If i use VS2010 with 64 bit target, the program works fine.

Comment: This problem seems very specific to the UEFI environment.  VS2012 might not produce the expected format or might misinterpret some of the header file contents.

Comment: See [Visual Studio 2012 breaking changes](http://www.google.com/search?num=40&q=Visual+Studio+2012+breaking+changes). Check out the ones that changed structure layout and padding. That seems to be the pain point for many folks. Also see [Breaking Changes in Visual C++ 2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531344%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): *"The default architecture for x86 builds is changed to SSE2 ... If you want to revert to previous behavior, then use the /arch:IA32 compiler flag to specify the architecture as IA32."* Keep in mind you need OS support for MMX and SSE2.